# Apex includescript is disabling tabs in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, javascript, community, visualforce-component

I have this java script.  The purpose is to open a NEW tab on any outputlink field.  The script works but it disables my other tabs.  When I remove my **Includescript** the tabs work but any outputfield link I click it renders inside the same iframe.

```
<apex:includeScript value="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" />

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.openInPopup a').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.open(jQuery(this).attr('href'));
    });
});
```

Any advice?  Thanks in advance.  I know it has something to do with the value of the includescript.  There can be another option?

Comment: Instead using jquery and function to open link in new tab. I suggest use html base tag `<base target="_blank"/>` just add this tag in vf page it will open all the links in new tag.. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the same problem a couple years ago.

Try the following:

```
var $j = JQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j('.openInPopup a').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.open($j(this).attr('href'));
    });
});
```

It could be a conflict issue with Salesforce Tab javascript functions.

Hopefully this solve your problem.